# How to improve region boundary crossing accuracy (simulation) (geofencing)

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, ios-simulator, geofencing

Im putting together an app that fires a notification when the user leaves the house. So i've implemented region monitoring with a radius of 25.
The issue I'm having is when simulating (iPhone simulator 5.0), i set a custom location (home) set the region boundary. then input another custom location outside the region boundary i.e at the end of a street. But the app doesn't register the exiting of the region. Only when i set the home location and region, then change to Apple headquarters does it register and fire a notification.
The app switches to significant location change when in background mode. But it has the same issue when in foreground or background.
What im looking for, like the "Reminders" app, is for the app to fire a notification very soon after exiting/leaving the region boundary i.e walking to the end of a street. How do i make it more accurate?

here is some of my viewcontroller.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

  // Create empty array to add region events to.
  updateEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

  // Create location manager with filters set for battery efficiency.
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; //could try KLDistanceFilterNone;
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

  // Start updating location changes.
          [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  // Get all regions being monitored for this application.
  NSArray *regions = [[locationManager monitoredRegions] allObjects];

  // Iterate through the regions and add annotations to the map for each of them.
          for (int i = 0; i < [regions count]; i++) {
                    CLRegion *region = [regions objectAtIndex:i];
  RegionAnnotation *annotation = [[RegionAnnotation alloc] initWithCLRegion:region];
                    [regionsMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                    [annotation release];
          }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
  NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);

  // Work around a bug in MapKit where user location is not initially zoomed to.
          if (oldLocation == nil) {
  // Zoom to the current user location.
                    MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0);
                    [regionsMapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];
          }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
  NSString *event = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"didEnterRegion %@ at %@", region.identifier, [NSDate date]];

          [self updateWithEvent:event];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
  NSString *event = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"didExitRegion %@ at %@", region.identifier, [NSDate date]];
          [self updateWithEvent:event];
//implement local notification:
    UIApplication *app                = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if (notification == nil)
        return;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did You Lock Your House?"];
    notification.alertAction = @"Lock House";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    [notification release];
// ends here

//following is an alert for the case of exiting boundary whilst app is in foreground
    UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder didExitRegion" message:region.identifier delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

    [alr show];

    [alr release];
    //ends here
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error {
  NSString *event = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"monitoringDidFailForRegion %@: %@", region.identifier, error];

          [self updateWithEvent:event];
}

- (IBAction)addRegion {
  if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]) {
  // Create a new region based on the center of the map view.
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
  CLRegion *newRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord
                                                                                                                                                                              radius:25.0
                                                                                                                                                                   identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude]];

  // Create an annotation to show where the region is located on the map.
                    RegionAnnotation *myRegionAnnotation = [[RegionAnnotation alloc] initWithCLRegion:newRegion];
                    myRegionAnnotation.coordinate = newRegion.center;
                    myRegionAnnotation.radius = newRegion.radius;

                    [regionsMapView addAnnotation:myRegionAnnotation];

                    [myRegionAnnotation release];

  // Start monitoring the newly created region.
                    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:newRegion desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

                    [newRegion release];
          }
  else {
  NSLog(@"Region monitoring is not available.");
          }
}
```

This work has been derived from the "Regions" template.

Comment: Ive deployed the app on my iPhone, set a region between 15-25m and walked a good 50m outside the region and nothing. any recommendations?

Answer (score 6):

The iOS simulator is notoriously bad for geofence updates with exit/enter. One way you can confim this is to set up the geofence on your app to be your current location. Then, from the debug menu of the iOS simulator, press location and then Freeway Drive. Your device will now be simulating driving down a freeway, and if your simulator is like mine, it will not register a didExitRegion event.

Why? Regions are mostly determined by Apple's hidden algorithm using Wi-Fi, cell towers, and other applications on the phone requesting location. Seeing as a simulator doesn't use Wi-Fi or cell towers... region monitoring is going to be pretty impossible.

To test if the rest of your code is working after the region exit, you can create a button or something that manually fires your locationManager:didExitRegion: method. I also strongly suggest compiling the project on your device by plugging it in and changing from iPhone Simulator to your iOS device. You can then unplug your device and run your app from your phone to test it.

Answer (score 1):

That's about the best accuracy you will get. The region matching only uses cell tower triangulation, so in dense areas it might trigger at 50-100m while sparse areas it may takes 100's of meters.

If you want finer detail then that you will ned to use straight location services. But that will eat battery, so pick your poison.